# City names game

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, sorting

If you like, write a program which sorts cities according to the rules of city name game.

- Each name of the city should start from the last letter in the previous city name. E.g. `Lviv -> v -> Viden -> n -> Neapolis -> s -> Sidney -> y -> Yokogama -> a -> Amsterdam -> m -> Madrid -> d -> Denwer`
- In the sorted list first letter of the first city and last letter of the last <strike>shouldn't match anything</strike> doesn't have to be the same letter.
- You can assume city names have only letters.
- Program output should have same capitalization as input

Example:

```
% ./script Neapolis Yokogama Sidney Amsterdam Madrid Lviv Viden Denwer
["Lviv", "Viden", "Neapolis", "Sidney", "Yokogama", "Amsterdam", "Madrid", "Denwer"]
```

Comment: Can we assume that there will always be a valid solution?

Comment: @Gareth yes, you can

Comment: the second rule - "[...] shouldn't match anything" - is it a requirement or just a statement saying that it's OK to have mismatch between the first and last letter? (ex: is a list like `["Viden" ... "Lviv"]` invalid?)

Comment: @w0lf by "shouldn't" I meant it doesn't have to, it is not compulsory. So your example is valid.

Comment: Hint: If you want a *nice* solution, you can reduce this to the calculation of eulerian paths, where each letter is a vertex and each word is an edge. (For instance, *Berlin* is the edge *B* → *N*) This is solvable in O(n), where n is the number of edges.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Ruby, <strike>58</strike> <strike>55</strike> 44 characters

```
p$*.permutation.find{|i|i*?,!~/(.),(?!\1)/i}
```

Yet another ruby implementation. Uses also case insensitive regex (as [Ventero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84/ventero)'s old [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6657)) but the test is done differently.

Previous version:

```
p$*.permutation.find{|i|(i*?,).gsub(/(.),\1/i,"")!~/,/}
```

Comment: Very nice! And I think you can get this down to 55 if you use `!~` instead of negating the whole expression.

Comment: That is smart regexp

Comment: @w0lf Of course! How could I not think of that?

Answer (score 5):

### Python (<s>162</s> <s>141</s> 124)

Brute force for the win.

```
from itertools import*
print[j for j in permutations(raw_input().split())if all(x[-1]==y[0].lower()for x,y in zip(j,j[1:]))]
```

Comment: I think you can remove the `&(j[0][0]!=j[-1][-1])` condition; see the question comments above.

Comment: **124** `from itertools import*;print[j for j in permutations(raw_input().split())if all(x[-1]==y[0].lower()for x,y in zip(j,j[1:]))]`

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around what's going on in this function.  What exactly are `j`, `x`, `y`?  How are they defined?  I'm sorry if these questions are lame, I'm new to Python and would like to work with it some more.

Comment: @MikeDtrick: `j` contains a permutation of the cities, which is generated with the `permutations` command. The big `if` on the end basically validates that for all values in `j`, the last letter of one value in `j` is the same as the first letter of the next value in `j`. Honestly, I don't know either what the `zip` does, `zip` works in mysterious ways.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation!  +1

Comment: Actually that was my +1 but I'm not greedy )). `zip` takes pair of lists and outputs list of pairs. `j` is permutation, `j[1:]` if permutation without first element. So `zip(j,j[1:])` is list of pairs: current word `x` and next word `y`).

Comment: I should use `zip` more, lol.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 113

Very similar to @beary605's answer, and even more brute-forced.

```
from random import*
l=raw_input().split()
while any(x[-1]!=y[0].lower()for x,y in zip(l,l[1:])):
 shuffle(l)
print l
```

Comment: Woohoo, bogo-sort style!

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby 1.9, <del>63</del> 54 characters

New solution is based on [Howard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1490/howard)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6658/84):

```
p$*.permutation.max_by{|i|(i*?,).scan(/(.),\1/i).size}
```

This uses the fact that there'll always be a valid solution.

Old solution, based on [w0lf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3527/w0lf)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6645/84):

```
p$*.permutation.find{|i|i.inject{|a,e|a&&e[0]=~/#{a[-1]}/i&&e}}
```

Comment: Nice idea with the `max_by`. And your new version inspired myself for an even newer (and shorter) one.

Comment: @Howard Thanks! Your new solution is really awesome, will be difficult to beat that. ;)

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby <s>74 72 104 103 71</s> 70

```ruby
p$*.permutation.find{|i|i.inject{|a,e|a[-1].casecmp(e[0])==0?e:?,}>?,}
```

**Demo:** http://ideone.com/MDK5c (in the demo I've used `gets().split()` instead of `$*`; I don't know if Ideone can simulate command-line args).

Comment: looks similar to my variant `$*.permutation{|p|p p if p.inject(p[0][0]){|m,e|m.casecmp(e[0])==0?e[-1]:?_}>?_}` but yours is 9 characters shorter!

Comment: `p$*.permutation.find{|i|i.inject{|a,e|a&&e[0]=~/#{a[-1]}/i&&e}}` is quite a bit shorter. A Ruby 1.8(!) solution which is even shorter: `p$*.permutation.find{|i|i.inject{|a,e|a&&a[-1]-32==e[0]&&e}}`

Comment: @Ventero Using case-insensitive regex is a brilliant idea! Please post this as your own answer; I'm not worthy to use that. :)

Comment: @Ventero the `-32` solution is also very ingenious, but it relies on the fact that names start with an uppercase letter and end with a lowercase, which may not always be the case.

Comment: @w0lf You're right, I thought I read in the specs that it would be the case, but obviously I'm mistaken. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>94</s> 74 bytes

```hs
g[a]=[[a]]
g c=[b:r|b<-c,r<-g[x|x<-c,x/=b],last b==[r!!0!!0..]!!32]
head.g
```

Recursively finds all solutions. -7 bytes if it's ok to output all solutions instead of the first. Thanks to @Lynn for getting rid of the pesky import, shaving 18 bytes off the score!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsIwFAD3fsVrcbRVdBMzCI7qIggSM7w2r2lompYktBX67UaF47jpGvQtGRNr9ooNoSxUojgKxn8SiYKK8fLglvKYV2t3zBWfl/nf84aVYm3QBygZ4y5Ntz@KQqTpfidiIB/Y1DvpIbsRDr3RHp592yvsEO5aWnrDqfOBnMQOriidlnAZ9QgPLcnCmexELkuSDrVlg9M2wApq@I/jp6oNKh/zahi@)

Comment: You can get rid of the `Data.Char` import with `last b==[r!!0!!0..]!!32`. Also, you don't need parens in `g[x|x<-c,x/=b]`

Comment: @Lynn nice, I somehow thought `fromEnum` would be a must. Funny, I took those parentheses away already once, but I must have copied from the wrong tab…

Answer (score 2):

#### GolfScript, 78 characters

```
" ":s/.{1${1$=!},{:h.,{1$-1={1$0=^31&!{[1$1$]s*[\](\h\-c}*;}+/}{;.p}if}:c~;}/;
```

A first version in GolfScript. It also does a brute force approach. You can see the script running on the example input [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJOZWFwb2xpcyBZb2tvZ2FtYSBTaWRuZXkgQW1zdGVyZGFtIE1hZHJpZCBMdml2IFZpZGVuIERlbndlciIKCiIgIjpzLy57MSR7MSQ9IX0sezpoLix7MSQtMT17MSQwPV4zMSYhe1sxJDEkXXMqW1xdKFxoXC1jfSo7fSsvfXs7LnB9aWZ9OmN%2BO30vOwo%3D).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>25</strike> 18 bytes (Improvements welcome!)

```
UżḢŒuE
ḲŒ!çƝẠ$ÐfḢK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVkApv9qZWxsef//VcW84biixZJ1RQrhuLLFkiHDp8ad4bqgJMOQZuG4okv///9OZWFwb2xpcyBZb2tvZ2FtYSBTaWRuZXkgQW1zdGVyZGFtIE1hZHJpZCBWaWRlbg)

```
UżḢŒuE        dyadic (2-arg) "check two adjacent city names" function:
Uż            pair (żip) the letters of the reversed left argument with the right argument,
  Ḣ           get the Ḣead of that pairing to yield just the last letter of left and the first letter of right,
   Œu         capitalize both letters,
     E       and check that they're equal!
ḲŒ!çƝẠ$ÐfḢK    i/o and check / fold function:
ḲŒ!            split the input on spaces and get all permutations of it,
   çƝẠ$        run the above function on every adjacent pair (çƝ), and return true if Ȧll pairs are true
       Ðf      filter the permutations to only get the correct ones,
         ḢK    take the first of those, and join by spaces!
```

Thanks to @Lynn for most of these improvements!

**25-byte solution:**

```
Uḣ1Œu=⁹ḣ1
çƝȦ
ḲŒ!©Ç€i1ị®K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/04Y7Fhkcnldo@atwJYnIdXn5s7ollXA93bDo6SfHQysPtj5rWZBo@3N19aJ33/////VITC/JzMosVIvOz89MTcxMVgjNT8lIrFRxzi0tSi1IScxV8E1OKMlMUfMoyyxTCMlNS8xRcUvPKU4sA)

```
Uḣ1Œu=⁹ḣ1      dyadic (2-arg) "check two adjacent city names" function:
Uḣ1Œu          reverse the left arg, get the ḣead, and capitalize it (AKA capitalize the last letter),
     =⁹ḣ1      and check if it's equal to the head (first letter) of the right argument.
çƝȦ            run the above function on every adjacent pair (çƝ), and return true if Ȧll pairs are true
ḲŒ!©Ç€i1ị®K     main i/o function:
ḲŒ!©           split the input on spaces and get all its permutations, ©opy that to the register
    Ç€         run the above link on €ach permutation,
      i1       find the index of the first "successful" permutation,
        ị®K    and ®ecall the permutation list to get the actual ordering at that ịndex, separating output by spaces
```

Comment: Some improvements: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsNAEIbvfYopFEykBHsVRIp4ENGLVBQRGbtjsnWzidlNS7zVSw9epHdBKiiCePAUraeGiCd9hvRFYhYKvf3MP9830yMhkrLs5F9FOsnH8XatSN/zcT17/r4vPh8a2d3F0W5ZrsKWh9IlBp0ifWxVixvz4YeJoANY0uugPdQrCq55aEXUt36ndhP@hvbJ2qkThyFFlu2gEGd0FaPYtOza0jx7yUbzm1feKqa3szfjzUbVebAWyl6sNAyqDGbKAlJ1g@9IwWWFm49/npoQUSiwy6Vb4TDg2ls0DUDJQGHfVAjniSan3CcMA8EVHAeXgYs@wgFnkhJo@0pTxNCHPWQRZ3DIGcl/ "Jelly – Try It Online") I wrote a little changelog in the "Input" field. (Oh, after `Ðf` I use `X` to pick a random solution instead of the first one, but `Ḣ` works just as well.)

Comment: @Lynn Thank you so much! The zip part was very clever, and I think I can use that `Ðf` quick in a lot of my other programs to save some space!

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
←fΛ~=o_←→P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbhLRzs@ts8@OBrEdtkwL@//8freSXmliQn5NZrKSj5FOWWQakXFLzylOLgIzgzJS81EogIywzJTUPSEfmZ@enJ@YmApm@iSlFmSlAhmNucUlqUUpirlIsAA)

#### Explanation

```
←fΛ~=(_←)→P  -- example input: ["Xbc","Abc","Cba"]
          P  -- all permutations: [["Xbc","Abc","Cba"],…,[Xbc","Cba","Abc"]]
 f           -- filter by the following (example with ["Xbc","Cba","Abc"])
  Λ          -- | all adjacent pairs ([("Xbc","Cba"),("Cba","Abc")])
   ~=        -- | | are they equal when..
     (_←)    -- | | .. taking the first character lower-cased
         →   -- | | .. taking the last character
             -- | : ['c'=='c','a'=='a'] -> 4
             -- : [["Xbc","Cba","Abc"]]
←            -- take the first element: ["Xbc","Cba","Abc"]
```

#### Alternatively, 10 bytes

We could also count the number of adjacent pairs which satisfy the predicate (`#`), sort on (`Ö`) that and take the last element (`→`) for the same number of bytes:

```
→Ö#~=o_←→P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbpMPTlOts8@MftU0AcgL@//8freSXmliQn5NZrKSj5FOWWQakXFLzylOLgIzgzJS81EogIywzJTUPSEfmZ@enJ@YmApm@iSlFmSlAhmNucUlqUUpirlIsAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 236 chars

Define the list of cities:

```
d = {"Neapolis", "Yokogama", "Sidney", "Amsterdam", "Madrid", "Lviv", "Viden", "Denver"}
```

Find the path that includes all cities:

```
c = Characters; f = Flatten;
w = Outer[List, d, d]~f~1;
p = Graph[Cases[w, {x_, y_} /;x != y \[And] (ToUpperCase@c[x][[-1]]== c[y][[1]]) :> (x->y)]];
v = f[Cases[{#[[1]], #[[2]], GraphDistance[p, #[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@  w, {_, _, Length[d] - 1}]];
FindShortestPath[p, v[[1]], v[[2]]]
```

Output:

```
{"Lviv", "Viden", "Neapolis", "Sidney", "Yokogama", "Amsterdam","Madrid", "Denver"}
```

The above approach assumes that the cities can be arranged as a path graph.

---

The graph p is shown below:

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

## C, 225

```
#define S t=v[c];v[c]=v[i];v[i]=t
#define L(x)for(i=x;i<n;i++)
char*t;f;n=0;main(int c,char**v){int i;if(!n)n=c,c=1;if(c==n-1){f=1;L(2){for(t=v[i-1];t[1];t++);if(v[i][0]+32-*t)f=n;}L(f)puts(v[i]);}else L(c){S;main(c+1,v);S;}}
```

Run with country names as the command line arguments

Note:

- brute force generation of permutations
- for checking it assumes that country names start with an upper case and end in lower case.
- assumes there is only one answer
- In C, assumes that the **v array of main() is writable

Comment: Not sure it is exactly valid, but if you do `#define L(x)for(int i=x;i<n;i++)` and don't declare `i` at the beginning of `main` you save 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

### J, <strike>69</strike> <strike>65</strike> <strike>60</strike> <strike>59</strike> 54 characters

Somewhat off the pace.

```
{.l\:+/2=/\|:tolower;"2({.,{:)@>l=.(i.@!@#A.]);:1!:1[1
```

Example:

```
   {.l\:+/2=/\|:tolower;"2({.,{:)@>l=.(i.@!@#A.]);:1!:1[1
Neapolis Yokogama Sydney Amsterdam Madrid Lviv Viden Denwer
+----+-----+--------+------+--------+---------+------+------+
|Lviv|Viden|Neapolis|Sydney|Yokogama|Amsterdam|Madrid|Denwer|
+----+-----+--------+------+--------+---------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**C#, 398**

And here is C# with Linq 5 cents

```
IEnumerable<string>CityNameGame(string[]input){var cities=new List<string>(input);string lastCity=null;while(cities.Any()){var city=lastCity??cities.First();lastCity=cities.First(name=>string.Equals(city.Substring(city.Length-1),name.Substring(0,1),StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));cities.RemoveAll(name=>name==city||name==lastCity);yield return string.Format("{0}→{1}",city,lastCity);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>374 bytes</s> 302 bytes

```cs
using System;using System.Linq;class Program{static void Main(string[] s){Func<char, char>u=(c)=>char.ToUpperInvariant(c);var S="";int I=0,C=s.Count();for(;I<C;I++)S=Array.Find(s,x=>u(s[I][0])==u(x[^1]))==null?s[I]:S;for(I=0;I<C;I++){Console.Write(S+" ");S=C>I?Array.Find(s,x=>u(S[^1])==u(x[0])):"";}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBtS8MwFIX/yqWfGjbLXt1Llo5RGRSmCPEFKRVCGmewTWaS1o2x316zCSL45XIuh/vcw@H2imsj2ra2Um2BHqwTFf67RBupPjEvmbVwb/TWsOpoHXOSQ6NlAbdMqtA64y@yHCw6rmvFF/ydmS6cZ1yTkCMSn3X0oB93O2FS1TAjmXLewV4CJUGApXKQkl43ITZKdO1dhN@0CXG6SHDa6SBKVsawQ7SWqghtd0/iOrRZmme9HBFSh/vstZ8jL1VdlsuzM6cXgqf@Qo6JVlaXIno20omQdgIIEKYkidPlfzy9IH/g/gua@5yn06lt2zvBdrqUFl70h96yigGVhRIHWFW@NlOwyldTGN/QppENPMlCKLgR6kuYdjKF4QgGQ5jOoD@A0RiuJzDrwfj6Gw)

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] s)
    {
        Func<char, char> u = (c) => char.ToUpperInvariant(c);
        var S = "";
        int I = 0, C = s.Count();

        for (; I < C; I++)
            S = Array.Find(s, x => u(s[I][0]) == u(x[^1])) == null ? s[I] : S;

        for (I = 0; I < C; I++)
        {
            Console.Write(S + " ");
            S = C > I ? Array.Find(s, x => u(S[^1]) == u(x[0])) : "";
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLbtswEDxXX7HQJSTsKM77oTJBoMKAAKcoyrRBEOTASqxCVCJdknZtGPp2lbQqR2qyF@1iRzvDmczsZ0rzZmGELICujeVVHPSnaCbk7zjISmYMfNGq0KwKNgG4MpZZkcFSiRzumJDIWO1@fHoGpguDt5gW6eun42HZyz@Qh4CQPeQQ7WuK3Dai81JYtAd7GMeDdaKkUSWPHrSw3KnkqAeod93BwU4WBQIbCD9zNlelMOEYwkf1SxWsYr6nIpd87bvbyj1d56zywx3Ltch9N1uKpf9@FzmXvvnE5R@uQ6jjHt0UUdyfO51fOcs7iXXwxsHpq32dd82SaaAkDGMhLaRkMk6IiRK1kNYdcoaiOP2YxOlohCm51Zqto6mQOTLjFbk2T@lzRBc/2qtoMj7E0b36Np9zjTAhq95uFc24LOzLfh/iMHJRljf@zhXdsjkFO8LNwH5ERyGEOKYkuU5v/pdCe1z0Pa6hnKFUfOXeXzcf6qBumi466HKDNjTYJQZtXOCzgm1Q0KbUnF/A8QkcHcPFJRwewckpnJ3D5QROz/4C)

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

var S = "";
int I = 0, C = s.Count();
for (; I < C; I++)
    S = Array.Find(
        s, x =>
        s[I].Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() == x.Substring(x.Length - 1).ToUpper()
    ) == null ?
    s[I] :
    S;
for (I = 0; I < C; I++) {
    Console.Write(S + " ");
    S = C > I ? Array.Find(s, x => S.Substring(S.Length - 1).ToUpper() == x.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()) : "";
}
```

Comment: [279 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDLasMwFER/5eKVRBKT96OKXIJLwJCGgvqgGBeEraaitpRKlpsQ8u2u0my66OYylzMzi8ltL9dGtK2zUu2AHW0tKvL3CTdSfZG85NbCw8nWvJY5NFoWcM@lQrY23ptmFp/WTuXL/IOb7uVEjqIc0@iiw0f9tN8Lk6iGG8lV7QnxEhgNAiJVDTG1YaydJ7ib0Ji8a4NI0utFfYIZXRnDj@FaqgLZ7oFGDtk0ydJ@hil16JC@DTLspXJleXshN@xa0Okky5j8l2e/mWva12Aca2V1KcIXI2uBWCeAAJPzuW3breB7XUoLr/pT73jFgclCiSOsKr@PKXjllyiMH2TTyAaeZSEU3An1LUw7m8NoDMMRzBcwGMJ4AtMZLPowmf4A "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
á kÈäÈÌkYÎÃd
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=4SBryOTIzGtZzsNk&input=WyJOZWFwb2xpcyIsIllva29nYW1hIiwiU2lkbmV5IiwiQW1zdGVyZGFtIiwiTWFkcmlkIiwiTHZpdiIsIlZpZGVuIiwiRGVud2VyIl0)

Answer (score 0):

## K, 96

```
{m@&{&/(~).'+(,_1_1#'x),,-1_-1#'x}@'$m:{$[x=1;y;,/.z.s[x-1;y]{x,/:{x@&~x in y}[y;x]}\:y]}[#x;x]}
```

.

```
k){m@&{&/(~).'+(,_1_1#'x),,-1_-1#'x}@'$m:{$[x=1;y;,/.z.s[x-1;y]{x,/:{x@&~x in y}[y;x]}\:y]}[#x;x]}`Neapolis`Yokogama`Sidney`Amsterdam`Madrid`Lviv`Viden`Denver
Lviv Viden Neapolis Sidney Yokogama Amsterdam Madrid Denver
```