# Chaining Words Together

Tags: code-golf, string

Given two words and a list as input, your program must (in as few characters as possible, of course) find the shortest way to "chain" the first word to the last using the ones in the list. Two words are "chained" if their first and last letters are the same, e.g. "Food" and "Door".

Your program will take input as a string with words separated by spaces, and output a list (in whatever format is most convenient: string, array/list type, etc) of the completed chain.

Examples:

`Input: joke corn tan disc need eat`
`Output: joke eat tan need disc corn`

The first two words in the input list are the first and last words in the chain, and the rest are the constituent words.

`Input: best fry easy elf mean tame yam nice`
`Output: best tame elf fry`
NOT: `best tame easy yam mean nice elf fry`

`Input: rug gunned orange purple gains pore soup emo ending`
`Output: rug gunned`

`Input: %3gioxl? 6699-4 !f!!&+ ?4; ;78! +6`
`Output: %3gioxl? ?4; ;78! !f!!&+ +6 6699-4`
The "words" don't have to be real words; for the purpose of the challenge, any ASCII character except the space will count as part of a word.

`Input: mouth rich frame inspire item sold`
Output when the first and last word are impossible to chain is undefined, so handle it however's shortest.

Comment: Will the words have hyphens?

Comment: @LeakyNun Count hyphenated words as one word. I forgot to address "words" with symbols in them, however - I'll add a usage example for it.

Comment: Could you define "word" in your challenge?

Comment: Related: [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68725/play-the-word-chain), [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44922/building-a-long-chain-of-words), [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/city-names-game)

Comment: @LeakyNun does the second-to-last example (edited in now) work?

Comment: Hardly a definition. Did you mean `/[^ ,|]+/`?

Comment: Referring to the delimiters? I tried to address that above, check the bolded bit.

Comment: Is the definition of "word" `/[^ ,|]+/`? Also, your delimiter is two characters long.

Comment: Alright، I'm rusty with regex and had forgotten what the carer means, my bad. I reworked the whole delimiter situation, is this better?

Comment: {Why do / Do} we need to use delimiters rather than input and/or output as arrays (ordered tuples)?

Comment: That was an oversight - input must be taken as a string with words separated by spaces, but the output may be in any format you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth - 42 bytes

Complete brute force. Surprisingly fast, finishes all possible the test cases in seconds. Will run forever with impossible inputs.

```
Acczd]2.VZIJf.Amqhedehd,VTtTm++hGdeG^HbhJB
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Acczd%5D2.VZIJf.Amqhedehd%2CVTtTm%2B%2BhGdeG%5EHbhJB&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=joke+corn+tan+disc+need+eat%0Abest+fry+easy+elf+mean+tame+yam+nice%0Arug+gunned+orange+purple+gains+pore+soup+emo+ending%0A%253gioxl%3F+6699-4+%21f%21%21%26%2B+%3F4%3B+%3B78%21+%2B6&debug=1).

Comment: `Impoosible` Is that like a mongoose?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ :/

Comment: "Imøøsible" is the only valid choice here.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>51</s> 48 bytes

FGITW.

```
=cQdMqeGhHL++hQb@Q1holN{+Fmf.AgVTtTyM+]Y._d.p>Q2
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3DcQdMqeGhHL%2B%2BhQb%40Q1holN%7B%2BFmf.AgVTtTyM%2B%5DY._d.p%3EQ2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22joke+corn+tan+disc+need+eat%22%0A%22best+fry+easy+elf+mean+tame+yam+nice%22%0A%22rug+gunned+orange+purple+gains+pore+soup+emo+ending%22%0A%22%253gioxl%3F+6699-4+!f!!%26%2B+%3F4%3B+%3B78!+%2B6%22%0A%22mouth+rich+frame+inspire+item+sold%22&debug=0)